# Scroll down the dynamically loading webpage

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am using this code given below to scroll down a dynamically loading webpage.

```
Time_delay =3

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(Time_delay)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

The above code does not work when I am performing the operation on the webpage [This page](https://quizizz.com/admin/search/amazon)

Could you please help me how can I achieve the scrolling down the page.

I have tried with the code. The code works on other website.

Answer (score 0):

This site uses infinite scrolling on the `app-body-container` element. Your code is attempting to scroll on the whole window, which is already in full view (nothing to scroll); thus it doesn't do what you expect.

Whether this is the best way, I'm not sure, but this will scroll indefinitely:

```py
while True:
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('app-body-container').scrollHeight")
    driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('app-body-container').scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);", scroll_height)
```

It works by getting the scroll height of the `app-body-container` element and then scrolling that element from 0 to the height. This could be improved by not scrolling from 0 every time by setting the last height in a variable and using it.

You will need to adapt this code to your own usage by deciding when it should stop scrolling, as it will currently do so forever, even if the page stops loading new content.